# What causes a UIView subview to take fullscreen?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, subview, uiwindow

I have a project which loads a `UIViewController` aka `appViewController` to the `UIWindow` full screen. I then am adding another `UIViewController` aka `menuViewController` to the `UIWindow`. The `menuViewController` has a xib with a `UIView` with dimensions of **480 x 35**. I add the `menuViewController` to the `UIWindow` like this:

```
MenuViewController *tempController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:kMenuViewController bundle:nil];

self.menuViewController = tempController;
[tempController release];

menuViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(17, 240);

[window insertSubview:menuViewController.view aboveSubview:appViewController.view];
```

The problem is that `menuViewController` is **NOT** respecting my `center` call and actually taking on `fullscreen` and covering my `appViewController`.

In Interface Builder I saw a property called: `Autoresize Subviews` checked for the `UIWindow`. I tried unchecking this and even for the subview and still does not work.

**NOTES:**
This project was updated from (which worked perfectly fine):

> Built with: Xcode 3.x.x (forgot exact)
>
> Base iOS: 3.0
>
> Target iOS: 2.2

And updated to:

> Built with: Xcode 4.3.1
>
> Base iOS: Latest (5.1)
>
> Target iOS: 4.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by editing the size of the view controller a few seconds after it was loaded, the problem was fixed.